# How to extend built-in function/add a property to a function?

Tags: node.js, typescript

`process.hrtime.bigint()` does not exist in the standard lib. I'm trying to add it in.

Here's what I've got:

#### types/bigint.d.ts

```
// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15096#issuecomment-400186862
type BigInt = number
declare const BigInt: typeof Number;

declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Process {
        hrtime: HighResTime
    }

    export interface HighResTime {
        (time?: [number, number]): [number, number];
        bigint(): BigInt
    }
}
```

Which I've added to my typeRoots in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types","./types"]
```

Using like:

```
///<reference path="../types/bigint.d.ts"/>

export default class ProgressBar {
    private startTime?: BigInt;

    start() {
        this.startTime = process.hrtime.bigint();
        this.render();
    }
```

But I get:

```
/home/me/Projects/xxx/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/ProgressBar.ts(19,41): error TS2339: Property 'bigint' does not exist on type '(time?: [number, number] | undefined) => [number, number]'.
```

If I remove the `<reference>` to `bigint.d.ts` then it gets even worse, and complains the type `BigInt` doesn't exist (TS2304) -- which doesn't make much sense to me, i thought that was the point of the typeRoot?

But the bigger issue is that even with the reference, TS still doesn't like `process.hrtime.bigint()`, so I'm guessing I didn't extend the `Process` interface properly. How do I do it right?

Comment: It's working for me, whether by `tsc -p .` or `ts-node src/ProgressBar.ts`, though I do get an error "Duplicate identifier 'hrtime'" in `types/bigint.d.ts`.  Process.hrtime is declared as a function in the Node typings, and overwriting it with another type isn't really supported; it may be that in your case, TypeScript is choosing the wrong definition for some reason.  Your best option may be to fork the Node typings.